# Multiple style blocks with crossed out declarations in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm curious why in Chrome Developer Tools when I'm checking out styles I have multiples of the exact same declarations? Usually they are one on top of the other and the second blocks declarations are all crossed out. Am I doing something wrong, or is there an option to remove the second block, or am I completely misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing you all the declarations that apply to a given. The crossed off declarations indicate that they've been overridden (usually by one higher up on the list). If they are all exactly the same, that meens you have multiple identical style declarations in your code. You'll need to edit the css files directly to remove them.